# How to correctly rotate div with hover handler?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, gsap

I'm trying to create image, that rotating with scrolling, on hover on it it will rotate to 0 deg (to initial state), when hover leaves, image rotates back to already rotated deg

Hook for rotate image while scrolling.

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                const rotation = window.scrollY / 10;
                imageRef.current.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
                setRotated(rotation) //set state of rotation
            });
        });
    }, []);
```

Here I am handling hover event but it lags and shows unpredictable behavior (sometimes it detects initial state (0 deg) wrong and rotate it to negative degs, or drastically changes current state on hover and just instantly jumps firstly on +10deg and immidiately rotates back to negative degs)

```
const hoverHandler = (state: string) => {
    switch (state) {
        case 'hover':
            gsap.to(imageRef.current, {rotation: `-=${rotated}`})
            setHovered(true)
            break
        case 'leave':
            gsap.to(imageRef.current, {rotation: `${rotated}`})
            setHovered(false)
            break
    }
}
```

so the image. Furthermore I want to change my image with opacity transition (for smooth) after rotation animation onhover

```
 return <img
        src={logo}
        alt=""
        className={classes['logo']}
        ref={imageRef}
        onMouseOver={() => hoverHandler('hover')}
        onMouseLeave={() => hoverHandler('leave')}
    />
```

Comment: Can you please share with me how your output looks right now? What do you want to change? It would be fine if you could share your code in the code sandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-pine-0nu97j?file=/src/Logo.tsx

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/9038574?key=5a2a634b047040e9a494df7a69362a58 the idea

Comment: Please upload it to a website like imgur, the video was deleted from that website. @simplesample

Comment: try again, rmk the link

Comment: @simplesample can you try wrapping the `hoverHandler` with a debounce function? I guess the unpredictable behaviour is due to onMouseOver and onMouseLeave events dispatching around the same time when the element rotates and the cursor goes in and out of the element's surface.